# Verify: Prove that $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Prove that $(A \times B) \cap (C \times D) = (A \cap C) \times (B \cap D)$

$x \in (A \times B) \cap (C \times D) \Leftrightarrow x\in (A \times B) \land x\in (C\times D) $ (1)

Every $x$ is therefore a tuple of the form $(x_1,x_2)$.

$x\in A \times B \implies x_1 \in A \land x_2\in B $

$x\in C \times D \implies x_1 \in C \land x_2 \in D$

Therefore: $(x_1 \in A \land x_2 \in B) \land (x_1 \in C \land x_2 \in D)
\\ \implies (x_1 \in A \land x_2 \in C) \land (x_2 \in B \land x_2 \in D)
\\ \implies (x_1 \in A\cap C) \land (x_2 \in B \cap D)
\\ \implies x = (x_1,x_2) =(A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)$

Is this a sound proof?

Comment: It seems to me that you only proved $(A\times B)\cap (C\times D)\subseteq (A\cap C)\times (B\cap D)$.

Comment: Just use equivalences and it will work in both direction.

Comment: @Gae.S. I should have used the double arrows to show that these go in both directions, which hence shows that they are reciprocally subsets, and hence are equivalent.

Comment: @zkutch's tip halves the full proof's length. You can neaten it further by writing $x$ as $(a,\,b)$ to begin with so you don't need to write $x=(x_1,\,x_2)$, or even name $x$.